# pure css sidebar dropdown (no bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to write a sidebar with expandable dropdown options and some smooth animations using pure css/js/html/jquery (no bootstrap).
I've written a sidebar like this before using bootstrap, see this example:
https://bootstrap-menu.com/demos/sidebar-nav-accordion.html

But now I'm trying to achieve the same end result using only pure css as a challenge, and to eliminate my reliance on bootstrap.

I've been working with this example so far but haven't gotten an expand/collapse accordion working yet:

```js
var isSidebarOpen = false;

function sideNavClicked(){
    console.log('sideNavClicked()')
    isSidebarOpen ? closeNav() : openNav();
}

function openNav() {
console.log('openNav')
    isSidebarOpen=true;
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
console.log('closeNav')
    isSidebarOpen=false;
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Expand This ▼</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Coverage</a></li>
    </ul>
  
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="sideNavClicked()">☰</button>  
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Was wondering what small scale example I could incorporate into this code? Hosted on jsfiddle as well:
https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/7wey2ujt/7/

Answer (score 1):

With your animation, try:

```
#animatedObj{
    filter: opacity: 0; /* or something else because there will be a gap */
    -webkit-transition: filter 200ms linear;
}
.show{
    filter: opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: filter 200ms linear;
```

and then in your JS/Jquery

```
$('#animatedObj').click(function(){
    $('#animatedObj').toggleClass('show')
    if($('#animatedObj').hasClass('show')){
        $('#animatedObj').append("<list thing>")
    }else{
        $('#animatedObj').remove("<list thing>")
    }
})
```

Keep in mind that you may want a different css effect to be there instead.

Comment: Though it should generally be fast using an ID selector, might as well assign `$(this)` in that handler to a variable then reuse that instead of re-selecting three times

Comment: Also, don't need to re-define that transition. Probably don't need the webkit prefix either.

Comment: I tried to implement your code, added the id 'animatedObj' to my sidebar <ul> element but it hasn't expanded/collapsed the element https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/e71j38c9/3/

Comment: So...When I had `<list thing>`, I just meant whatever code that you had that you wanted to show. `<list thing>` Will not do anything because it is a tag. You need something like `<ul><li>pickles</li><li>horseradish</li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for
I added a few lines into your javascript code and also added a few classes in html including `ul` tag and `a` tag using which the submenu is collapsed.
I have have added comments in the code that I added to let you know what was modified...

---

Take a look at the snippet

---

```js
var isSidebarOpen = false;

function sideNavClicked() {
  console.log("sideNavClicked()");
  isSidebarOpen ? closeNav() : openNav();
}

function openNav() {
  console.log("openNav");
  isSidebarOpen = true;
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  console.log("closeNav");
  isSidebarOpen = false;
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

////------------Added Line of Code----------------
const list = document.querySelector(".toggle--list");
// const submenu
document.querySelector(".submenu").classList.add("hidden");
list.addEventListener("click", e => {
  document.querySelector(".submenu").classList.toggle("hidden");
});
///////////////////
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  
  .sidebar a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .sidebar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .sidebar .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  .openbtn:hover {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  
  #main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
  }
  
  /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
  }

/*-----------added line of code----------------*/
.hidden{
    display:none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
/*---------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#" class="toggle--list">Expand This ▼</a>
      <!--Added classname here-->
      <ul class="submenu">
        <!--Added classname here-->
        <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Coverage</a></li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <button class="openbtn" onclick="sideNavClicked()">☰</button>
      <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
      <p>
        Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this
        content to the right.
      </p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my solution here, hope it can solve your problem.
I added some animations.

```js
var isSidebarOpen = false;

function sideNavClicked() {
  isSidebarOpen ? closeNav() : openNav();
}

function openNav() {
  isSidebarOpen = true;
  document.getElementById('mySidebar').classList.add('sidebar-show');
  document.getElementById('main').classList.add('main-show');
}

function closeNav() {
  isSidebarOpen = false;
  document.getElementById('mySidebar').classList.remove('sidebar-show');
  document.getElementById('main').classList.remove('main-show');
}

function toggleMenuItem(element){
    document.getElementById(element.dataset.ulid).classList.toggle("ul-show");
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.super-animation{
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
}

.main-content{
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 15px);
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(calc(-100%), 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(calc(-100%), 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(calc(-100%), 0, 0);
}

.sidebar.sidebar-show{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  padding: 16px;
}

#main.main-show{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
}

.main-content .sidebar ul{
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 200ms ease-out;
}

.main-content .sidebar ul.ul-show{
  transition: max-height 200ms ease-in;
  max-height: 400px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="main-content">
  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar super-animation">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a data-ulid="expand_this" onclick="toggleMenuItem(this);" href="#">Expand This ▼</a>
      <ul id="expand_this">
        <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Coverage</a></li>
      </ul>

    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main" class="super-animation">
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="sideNavClicked()">☰</button>  
    <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
    <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```